# Python get new sub-dictionary with same structure using only certain nested value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict kind of in this form

```py
d = {
    "a": {
        "b": {"id": 1, "time": 1234},
        "c": {"id": 3, "time": 2345},
    },
    "d": {
        "e": {"id": 5, "time": 3456},
        "f": {"id": 7, "time": 4567},
        "g": {"id": 9, "time": 5678},
    },
}
```

Is there a straight-forward way that I can get "sub"-dicts like

```py
d_sub1 = {"a": {"b": {"id": 1, "time": 1234}}}
d_sub3 = {"d": {"e": {"id": 5, "time": 3456}}}
```

That's to say, I want only some of the nested value, namely the `{"id": 1, "time": 1234}`, but have the structure reserved, namely the `{"a": {"b": {XXX}}}`

I could work around with `d_sub1 = {"a": {"b": d["a"]["b"]}}`, but that feels a little redundant as I have to write `"a"` and `"b"` twice.

Also in reality the dictionary depth is much larger than 2, it would be really long to write.

So is there some good ways?

If you are interested in the background, my colleague write something using `Process` with which I have to pass the whole dict (`d`) to each of them and record the changed part each (`d_sub1`) then merge all the changed parts (`d_sub1`, `d_sub3`, ...) to a new dict to replace `d`.

*As stated in comments, I had the idea of creating a class which generates the keys for me. [live example](https://tio.run/##fZJNboMwEIX3nGLqFVQRUkrTtEjZtd1U7QUQsggeUotgkHGqooiz0@EnMYmqsLE9/ub5PeyqMd@lCrou02UBpqmk2oEsqlIbuHccARs4OkAfS1g4TYfltl8yKWhYLoAZWWA/fQge24WlUksFliJoNVHTwMSlOtq@le2jtqe5emaptaUIWs@pnaVeLEXQs/XQUlReH7bLPu8Y9VbCth3xYMAH77csE@446T6pa/hsXmVqwuFcgRlwLpU0nLs17rMFCC88G@8rPu9vQFzVcqpFsTMT2aGRBouzTj7TkRnkoEoDUp00/Ryb2p0x/acTWSN8YPOmdaldRjM4tvBFne/lQYk75melLhLjUrfnnXtxX@Ol0uTST6oKlXBz75/dPtc0i/L40giagx692oz4a3SSmiHfzPhM5lwjl5SY0mr8QV2jcCdDV4GHx52HIFrn6mhB9yX7/6qSAjmHzQYY50UiFedsFCkaLugmSWK8UleMKelVnDYmJKL3FEf0nGL/FGJEKy0VBZoaPKfr/gA)*

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what you're trying to accomplish. Do you just want the first sub-dictionary? Could you maybe show us a less theoretical example and expected results (using real data-structures)?

Comment: TBH looks just fine, other then that you are bound to do some iteration which will be a bit more convoluted.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Sure, I have edited the question to provide more information.

Comment: @ElevenLee So basically, you want to get all sub-dictionaries, where the "end" of the sub-dictionary is basically until there is no more nested dictionaries any more? That sounds like it could be solved using a recursive function if that is the case.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Not exactly, I think it's a much simpler problem. I want to use a simpler (also shorter) way to write `d_sub1 = {"a": {"b": d["a"]["b"]}}`. I have the idea of wrapping the dict in some class and rewrite the `__getitem__` method, so it generates the keys for me. Want to see if there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using recursion and generators:

```
d = {
    "a": {
        "b": {"id": 1, "time": 1234},
        "c": {"id": 3, "time": 2345},
    },
    "d": {
        "e": {"id": 5, "time": 3456},
        "f": {"id": 7, "time": 4567},
        "g": {"id": 9, "time": 5678},
    },
}

class Depth_first_dict:
    def __init__(self, main_dict: dict):
        self.main_dict = main_dict
        for key, value in self.main_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict): # Create child
                self.main_dict[key] = Depth_first_dict(main_dict=value)

    def get_sub_dicts(self):
        """
            Loops over each key-value pair and recurses down the tree
            until terminating a sub_dictionary
        """
        is_end = True
        for key, value in self.main_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, self.__class__):
                is_end = False
                for child in value.get_sub_dicts():
                    yield {key: child}
        if is_end:
            yield self.main_dict

depth = Depth_first_dict(d)

for x in depth.get_sub_dicts():
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'id': 1, 'time': 1234}}}
{'a': {'c': {'id': 3, 'time': 2345}}}
{'d': {'e': {'id': 5, 'time': 3456}}}
{'d': {'f': {'id': 7, 'time': 4567}}}
{'d': {'g': {'id': 9, 'time': 5678}}}
```

Using generators, you can either generate all of the values as the same time by calling:

```
print(list(depth.get_sub_dicts()))
# [{'a': {'b': {'id': 1, 'time': 1234}}}, {'a': {'c': {'id': 3, 'time': 2345}}}, {'d': {'e': {'id': 5, 'time': 3456}}}, {'d': {'f': {'id': 7, 'time': 4567}}}, {'d': {'g': {'id': 9, 'time': 5678}}}]
```

Or you can generate them piece-meal:

```
depth_gen = depth.get_sub_dicts()
print(next(depth_gen))
print(next(depth_gen))
# {'a': {'b': {'id': 1, 'time': 1234}}}
# {'a': {'c': {'id': 3, 'time': 2345}}}
```